# Drawing a triangle vertex in a bubble diagram with feynmf package

Tags: feynmf

I would like to draw some Feynman diagrams using the `feynmf` package which contain a complex (triangular) vertex. Here is my attempt, which apparently reproduces the diagram which I want to achieve, however I have a few problems:

```
\begin{fmffile}{graf11}
{\begin{fmfgraph}(60,40)
\fmfleft{l}
\fmfright{r}
\fmfpoly{shaded}{z1,z2,z3}
\fmf{fermion,right=0.5}{l,z2}
\fmf{fermion,left=0.5}{l,z1}
\fmf{phantom}{z3,r}
\fmfdot{l}
\fmfdot{z1}
\fmfdot{z2}
\fmfdot{z3}
\end{fmfgraph}}
\end{fmffile}
```

My question is the following:

How can I draw only the triangular vertex without any propagation lines? I would like to avoid using phantom lines. It seems that drawing a standalone triangle (without any lines connected to it) with `fmfpoly` gives an error message.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please add a minimal working example http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that , with `\documentclass` ... `\end{document}`.

Comment: I reproduce your observation. However, you can make the propagation line very short by adding tension, e.g. `\fmf{phantom,tension=99}{z3,r}` .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what issue you are having. If it's just that you don't want to use a phantom line from `v3` to `r` you could just use `r` in the `fmfpoly` directly and avoid need for an extra vertex.

The code is:

```
\begin{fmffile}{graf11}
{\begin{fmfgraph}(60,40)
\fmfleft{l}
\fmfright{r}
\fmfpoly{shaded}{z1,z2,r}
\fmf{fermion,right=0.5}{l,z2}
\fmf{fermion,left=0.5}{l,z1}
\fmfdot{l}
\fmfdot{z1}
\fmfdot{z2}
\fmfdot{r}
\end{fmfgraph}}
```

which gives the output
[image: Feynman Diagram]